# Amazon S3 - Almacenando archivos de imágenes desde Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, imagen

Tengo un modelo personalizado de usuarios en el cual quiero adicionar un campo de avatar del usuario:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    # email
    # username
    # first_name
    # last_name   

    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='avatars',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Photo'
    )
```

He instalado los siguientes paquetes via `pip install`:

```
boto3==1.4.4
django-boto==0.3.11
django-storages==1.5.2
django-storages-redux==1.3.2
Pillow==4.0.0
```

Estoy con la siguiente configuración para Amazon S3 en mi archivo `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',

        # Third party apps
        'storages',

]

STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
)

#Amazon S3 Storage
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = get_env_variable('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = get_env_variable('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY =  get_env_variable('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

# Tell django-storages that when coming up with the URL for an item in S3 storage, keep # it simple - just use this domain plus the path. 
# (If this isn't set, things get complicated).
# This controls how the `static` template tag from `staticfiles` gets expanded, if you're using it. We also use it in the next setting.
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

# For media files to S3
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'assets'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

Tengo el archivo custom_storages.py el cual tiene dos clases, para almacenar los archivos estáticos y las imágenes. Estas clases heredan de la clase `S3BotoStorage`

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

# custom_storages.py 
class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

Cuando yo ejecuto `python manage.py collectstatic` mis archivos estáticos son subidos a Amazon S3 en mi respectivo bucket, dentro de un directorio llamado `assets` acorde a mi configuración dada. Esto trabaja bien como es esperado.

El inconveniente surge cuando existen imágenes que son subidas por actividad de los usuarios en mi aplicación, más precisamente cuando un usuario sube una imágen de su avatar.

Cuando lo hace a través del admin de Django (este admin no será utilizado por los usuarios) la imagen sube bien, pero cuando lo hago a través de mi aplicación, la imagen no sube, tal como se muestra acá.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque en mi administrador de Django las imágenes son subidas a S3 pero en mi aplicación desde un `forms.ModelForm` no se suben las imágenes?

¿He pasado alguna directiva de configuración por alto?

He visto que existe esta alternativa de una aplicación de terceros para ser utilizada, que se llama [django-s3-storage](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage)  pero no la he probado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás buscando donde no debes, te parece que el S3 es la causa del problema porque es el elemento con el cual estás menos familiarizado, seguro que esto tiene nombre. Yo buscaría en:

**Templates**: comprueba que el formulario es Post y multipart/form-data:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Vistas**: Comprueba que le pasas request.FILES al formulario en la vista:

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: La he leído y no entiendo nada. Y creo que nadie te va a responder. Yo creo que te solucioné el error que planteabas. Me parece que lo mejor es que: 1) borres la actualización de la pregunta y des esta pregunta por respondida. 2) plantees una nueva pregunta, pero no pegues todo ese rollo, tienes que lograr escribir el [mcvr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no todo ese rollo que no se entiende nada. salut!!

Comment: Tienes razón @danihp. He formulado una nueva pregunta por si de pronto tienes oportunidad de verla. Te agradezco tus orientaciones :) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78224/manejando-un-imagefield-en-django-renderizandolo-en-un-template-html