# Manejando un ImageField en Django - Renderizandolo en un template html

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, django-forms

Tengo un modelo personalizado de usuarios en el cual quiero adicionar un campo de avatar del usuario:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    # email
    # username
    # first_name
    # last_name  

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True) 

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars',blank=True,null=True,verbose_name='Photo')

    # Con este signal indico que el valor del campo username se
    # almacene tambien en el campo slug, para generar un URL amigable
    # cuando quiera ir a los datos de un usuario tipo `preferences/username`
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def post_save_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        slug = slugify(instance.username)
        User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(slug=slug)

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        if self.avatar and hasattr(self.avatar, 'url'):
            return self.avatar.url
```

El método `image_url()` anterior, se ha definido de esa manera porque cuando se crea un usuario por primera vez, éste no tiene asociado ningún avatar o imágen.

Entonces cuando llamo en el template el campo `avatar.url` este método examina si campo avatar tiene el atributo `url` y lo retorna para pintarlo en el template de la siguiente manera:

```
<img src="{{ object.image_url|default_if_none:'#' }}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="User Image">
```

Esto lo estoy haciendo en un template llamado `layout.html` del cual heredan todos mis templates.

En caso de no poder extraer el `url` del avatar, lo cual se daría cuando un usuario no tenga una fotografía asignada al ser creado, entonces no se renderiza nada en el template, o tendría una fuente desconocida en la etiqueta img en su atributo source

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera manejo un poco ese error que saldría que 
Cuando un usuario es creado, éste no tiene asociada, este error para ser más precisos:

```
raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)
ValueError: The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it.
[13/Jun/2017 15:10:16] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 500 183409
```

Esto salía porque antes en el template `layout.html` llamaba el campo avatar de la siguiente forma:

```
<img src="{{ userprofile.user.avatar.url }}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="User Image">
```

`userprofile` es un contexto que envio a este template en donde estan todos los datos del usuario, entre ellos el `avatar`

De alguna manera lo he gestionado de esa forma, teniendo el siguiente flujo de trabajo:

```
url(r"^preferences/(?P<slug>[\w.\-]+)/$",
        views.AccountSettingsUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='preferences'
    ),
```

Mi formulario `UserUpdateForm()` es bastante básico en donde llamo varios campos del usuario entre ellos el que me interesa que es `avatar`:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "avatar",)
            model = get_user_model()
```

Mi vista `AccountSettingsUpdateView` esta de la siguiente manera:
Como según se dice, la vista que maneja este formulario recibirá el archivo de datos (mi imagen del campo `avatar` en este caso) en el `request.FILES`, [como es el ejemplo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model), he dimensionado de alguna manera como podría quedar el manejo del request del formulario en mi vista, haciendo uso del método `post()`:

**Creo que mi problema puede estar acá con lo del** `request.POST, request.FILES` solo que no me oriento bien en esta parte

```
class AccountSettingsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    # Obtiene mi modelo de usuario personalizado
    model = get_user_model()
    # Obtiene el formulario a utilizar
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    context_object_name = 'preferences'

    def post(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if request.method=='POST':
            form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return super(AccountSettingsUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(AccountSettingsUpdateView, self).form_invalid(form)


    '''
    # Tenia mis dudas si sobreescribia el form_valid()
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserUpdateForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return super(AccountSettingsUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(AccountSettingsUpdateView, self).form_invalid(form)
        #return render(self.request, 'user_form.html', {'form':form})
    '''
```

Mi template `user_form.html` en donde renderizo el formulario es el siguiente:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block title_tag %}Accounts | Settings | iHost {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block body_content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Account Details</h1>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Lo que me sucede es que cuando entro a la opcion de **Settings** en mi aplicación, lo que llama al url `preferences/(?P<slug>[\w.\-]...` referenciado anteriormente, ahí mi imagen es renderizada porque este url llama a mi vista `AccountSettingsUpdateView` la cual tiene el formulario UserUpdateForm() en el cual el campo avatar es renderizado para subir una imagen.

Pero cuando voy a otra parte de mi aplicación, la imágen de avatar no es renderizada. No se si me expliqué bien, pero adjunto esta imagen animada para explicar lo que me sucede.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi imágen de avatar la cual la estoy renderizando en un form base que heredan todos los demas templates, persista en cualquier parte de mi aplicación?

¿Qué puede estar sucediendo? Sin duda debe haber algun detalle que estoy pasando por alto, tal vez en mi forms.py o en mi vista. Me inclino por esta última

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eso sucede porque el otras vistas no pasas la informacion del usuario, ya he pasado por eso y lo que hago es un mixin donde en el `get_context_data` le paso la información del perfil

```
class UserInformationMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserInformationMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.object.get(username=self.request.user.username)
        return context
```

en en el template `layout.html` muestras la informacion del usuario

```
{{ user.username }}
```

**actualizado**
para mostrar el avatar si el usuario esta autenticado sería mas o menos así:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <img src={{ user.avatar.url }}>
{% else %}
    <img src='avatar_default.jpg'>
{% endif %}
```

o algo por el estilo

Comment: @bgarcial  el problema es que esa informacion solo se va a mostrar cuando llames a la vista `AccountSettingsUpdateView` pero en las demas vistas no se muestra simplemente porque el contexto no es mandado por el servidor, la mejor manera para ahorarse codigo es hacer una clase mixin y que las demas hereden de ella. Saludos

Comment: Claro, entiendo, pondría toda mi lógica de get_users_profiles en una sola clase y la heredo en todas mis vistas. Pensaré en como tener el valor del campo avatar ... Sería en esa misma consulta que haces user = User.object.get(username=self.request.user.avatar) ... mas o menos ...

Comment: en todas las vistas cuyo template herede de `layout.html` debería heredar de la clase mixin que crees y no tendrías que tocar mas nada, solo la herencia de dichas vistas

Comment: @bgarcial mira la actualización de la respuesta para que veas

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente no es lo que buscas.

Pero en mi caso se resolvió con un **base64**, existen librerias que toman tu imagen y la convierten a base64 con javascript asi cuando llega tu imagen, lo que llega es un string enorme codificado en base64.

```
    image_base64 = form.cleanded_data['image_base64']
    image = image_base64.decode('base64')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
    nombreimagen = 'miimagen'
    metadata = {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}
    bucket.put_object(Key="{0}.jpg".format(nombreimagen), Body=image, Metadata=metadata)
```

Y listo eso guardara la imagen en el bucket. PERO como ves se necesita que este en base64. Si deseas mandar directamente el file, deberas codificar lo que te envía django. Para ello existen librerias como pillow (AKA PIL). Lo cual considero más complejo. Por que como menciono existen muchas liberias javascript que te generan la cadena en base64 que ademas te serviria como preview para el usuario vea la imagen que se va a subir.